# Проблема с выводом структуры

Tags: c

Я передаю структуру, которая содержит элемент указателя на другую структуру, но после передачи его в функцию testModule и после преобразование типа, она выводит разные символы.
В чем проблема?

(Преобразовывать moduleData в void обязательно, тк это тестовый код, позже я его аргументом передам в поток)

```
typedef struct postFields {
    char login[56];
    char passwd[56];

} postFields;

typedef struct moduleData {
    postFields * post_fields;

} moduleData;

void * testModule(void *p_module_data) {
    moduleData * module_data = (moduleData *)&p_module_data;

    printf("%s\n", module_data->post_fields[0].login);
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    postFields post_fields[] = {"Dima", "Dima19930322"};
    moduleData module_data;

    module_data.post_fields = (postFields *)&post_fields;

    testModule((void *)&module_data);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется это потому что я преобразовал moduleData в void, но не преобразовал postFields в void, но как это сделать я не знаю.

Comment: `(moduleData *)&p_module_data` - лишнее взятие адреса, это уже указатель. Еще тут нет никаких преобразований в `void`, есть только преобразования в указатель на `void`. Кроме того, следует определиться с языком С или С++.

Comment: Я не знаю C++, но знаю что во многом они схожи, и даже книги называют C/C++... .
Поправьте меня, если не прав.

Comment: В вопросах следует ставить тег только того языка, о котором идет речь в вопросе, а не всяких схожих. А еще функция `testModule` не имеет `return`, хотя объявлена, как возвращающая значение, что является UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moduleData * module_data = (moduleData *)&p_module_data;` - здесь вы берёте адрес локальной переменной. А надо было преобразовать само значение.

`moduleData * module_data = (moduleData *) p_module_data;`

---

*Ещё у вас много несоответствий типов, такого делать не следует.*

Перед фигурными скобками нужно ставить тип структуры, а сам массив тоже нужно со скобками.

```
postFields post_fields[] = {(postFields){"Dima", "Dima19930322"}};
```

Вы адрес массива грубо преобразовываете на адрес элемента, но желательно всё писать правильно без преобразований.

```
module_data.post_fields = &(post_fields[0]);
```

Comment: Опечатка, описанная до черты, уже было описана в комментарии. А практические все, что написано под чертой - не нужно, не вводите человека в заблуждение. Разве что элементы массива обрамлять фигурными скобками могло бы иметь смысл.

Comment: Я не ввожу в заблуждение, можно использовать например автоматическое преобразование без апострофа так : `module_data.post_fields = post_fields;` а у автора было с адреса массива на адрес элемента. @user7860670